# Getting the last x numbers from an infinite sequence in Ruby

Tags: ruby

This works in Ruby:

```
a = 4..Float::INFINITY
p a.take(4) #=> [4,5,6,7]
```

But I was wondering if it's possible to do something similar where the range would be from negative infinity up to a certain number, say 4, and have a method that will take the last, say 6 elements from that sequence, which would be [-1,0,1,2,3,4].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the last N numbers from a range `-infinity..4` is the same of selecting a range of `4..(4-N)`.

```
4.downto(4-5).to_a
# => [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1]
```

You can package it as a custom method

```
def lastn(from, n)
  from.downto(from-n).to_a
end
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the [last method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Range.html#method-i-last)?

```
a.last(6)
```

Comment: Have you tried it? If you run it with given `a`, it hangs forever (because of `INFINITY`)